# Adding a standard to PHP_CodeSniffer

Tags: php

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'd like to check compatibility of our code as we upgrade to PHP-5.4 e.g. deprecated functions and other things that will break scripts.

I installed `codesniffer` like so

```
sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

I'm trying to install the standard I found [here](http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2012/03/04/php-5-4-compatibility-checks-using-php_codesniffer/) to

```
/usr/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PHPCompatibility
```

but, `phpcs` doesn't seem to find it.

Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Comment: Looks like on ubuntu you need to place it here /usr/share/php/test/PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeSniffer/Standards

Comment: Just a small typo in your location above its tests: /usr/share/php/tests/PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeSniffer/Standards

Answer (score 4):

At my local machine it's installed here:

```
/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PHPCompatibility/
```

(Get it from [here](https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility). )

After that I can call it with:

```
phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility my_project/
```

Comment: verifying this on my local machine, but it have note installed via `apt` not `composer`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to copy directories, to make PHP_CodeSniffer new coding standards. Just use `phpcs --config-set` to set *installed_paths* to the extra directories containing coding standards.

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths /path/to/one
```

If you have more directories, you can separate them with a comma.

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths /path/to/one,/path/to/two
```

See [Configuration Options](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options).

> By default, PHP_CodeSniffer will look inside its own `src/Standards` directory to find installed coding standards. An installed standard appears when you use the `-i` command line argument and can be referenced using a name instead of a path when using the `--standard` command line argument. You can add install paths by setting the installed_paths configuration option.

When I install PHP_CodeSniffer coding standard like drupal/coder, I use the following command. (I also use Composer to install PHP_CodeSniffer.)

```bash
composer global require drupal/coder dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer
```

[dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer](https://packagist.org/packages/dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer) is a Composer installation plugin that makes the coding standards automatically available to PHP_CodeSniffer without setting *installed_paths* each time new coding standards are added.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to install it is by using Composer. Just add :

> "wimg/php-compatibility": "*"

to the require-dev section of your composer.json file and run :

> composer update

This should automatically install the PHPCS and the standard and allow you to run PHPCS by doing :

> vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility

Answer (score -2):

Simply run this command in your terminal:

```
which phpcs
```

You will get something like this:

```
/usr/bin/phpcs
```

Comment: `phpcs` is found. `phpcs` isn't _finding_ something else.